# Sessionless HTTPHandler

Tags: .net, session, httphandler, ashx, serial-processing

Can't find this anywhere.

Is it possible to make an HTTPHandler sessionless?

Sometimes I export huge files that take some time to build.  Waiting for an ashx to finish jams up the rest of my webmethod calls.

Does anyone know how to make an ashx sessionless?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ashx's are sessionless by default.

My problem was that I had 'IRequiresSessionState' when I didn't need to write anything to the session, so all I need is 'IReadOnlySessionState' which apparently only takes a snapshot of the session.